# Cut two pages by Preview at once

Tags: pdf, preview, bug

When scanning documents, many pages in a row have the same problem. An example where a lot of white empty space in the corner:
[image]

The application Preview allows selecting the area in a row along the two pages.
However, when choosing to cut, only the page where you started get cropped.
I think this is a bug in design and should be fixed.
In the example, there are 277 pages. It takes hours of time if I cannot crop pages in a row.

**Is there any way to cut pages in a row in Preview or other applications?**

Comment: I'd be happy to try cutting things using [PDF Pen Pro](http://www.smilesoftware.com/PDFpenPro/index.html). Can you upload a few pages of a sample document so I can verify it easily does what I assume it would do - let you edit and perhaps even script the cropping of pages.

Comment: somewhat on topic, please use "command-shift-4" (release all, than) "space-bar" for proper screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be achieved solely with Preview.

1. Show page thumbnails by clicking **Thumbnails** from the View Menu.

   [image]
2. Show the **Edit** toolbar, and choose the **Rectangular Selection** tool.

   [image]
3. Select the rectangle that you want to crop each page to.
4. #### Select (⌘-click) all the pages that you want to crop in the page thumbnails.

   The pages don't have to be sequential, and you can select all pages with ⌘A.
5. Click **Crop** in the toolbar.

   [image]

Comment: Can you crop multiple pages with this at once? This is the problem, not only one page.

Comment: @Masi Yes you can, I have used this method for ages :)

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you very much for your tip! Do you know how you can reverse the change after you save and close the document?

Comment: You lose the metada about Search-function, which is the negative side effect, but it does not matter because you can run text-recognition after cropping again.

Comment: @Masi Since the change overwrites the file, the only way to recover it is if you have Time Machine (local backups are sufficient - go to Browse Previous Versions) or Dropbox previous versions, or if you have a copy of the original files.